# How to check document file canbe support or not in Android

Tags: android

```
String mimetype = ".docx\tapplication/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
File file = new File(FilePath, filename);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimetype);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

I use above code to read a .docx file.
How can I check whether application can support the file format or not?
If not, below message:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Not be supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function like this and give it your intent. It will check if there is any app able to process this intent.

```
private boolean isIntentLaunchable(Intent intent)
{
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    if (activities.size() > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```